# What is effect of rollback on table data types in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

What is effect of rollback on table data types in SQL Server? Will it rollback the DML operations performed on table data types OR SQL Server just ignores by treating it like garbage?

Just curious to know...

Comment: You should accept some answers on your other questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are un affected by the `rollback`. This is one of the reasons why table variables are sometimes preferred to `#temp` tables (reduced logging overhead).

This behaviour can also be quite useful for persisting some information that you want to process after a `rollback`.

It is easy to test.

```
begin tran
declare @t table (c int)
insert into @t values(1)
rollback

select * from @t
```

Returns

```
c
-----------
1
```